# Double x-large font size in CSS

Tags: css

How can I double x-large font size in CSS in calc() function?

Sometimes xx-large font size is not enough. It looks like it's not working:

```
font-size: calc(x-large * 2);
```

I getting an error: Mismatched property value.

Comment: X-LARGE is not a number and so cannot be used in a calculation. You need to define a font size using a number.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `x-large` as a [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) and apply the calc on the var:

```
font-size: calc(var(--x-large) * 2);
```

Comment: But i can't do sth like this: `:root { 
--x-large: x-large;
 }`

Comment: why not? isn't `x-large` a variable you are referring to? It will be helpful to understand what `x-large` is, and where its value is coming from.